# Unique file name from list

Tags: python

I have list with file paths (as string) from different directories; Im trying to remove duplicate file name (it can be even from different directory). Now I loop through whole list, make a dictionary to remove the duplicates. Is there any other efficient way?

Answer (score -1):

try using set()

```
unique_list = set(list1)
```

or if you want list returned

```
unique_list = list(set(list1))
```

Comment: I want to compare only the file name not the entire path ... So this might not work.

Comment: @syv then post some examples of these

Comment: I have 3 entries {mypath/xyz.txt, mypath/log/xyz.txt, mypath/abc.txt} I would like to remove second entry as it has same file name "xyz.txt" irrespective of path. Result Im expecting is {mypath/xyz.txt, mypath/abc.txt}